# query.count() throws exception with Embeddable ID

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm not able to get the total count of my query.

```
JPAQuery query = super.prepareJPAQuery(userAccountHasWorkgroup).where(
    userAccountHasWorkgroup.workgroup.id.eq(workgroupId);
query.count();
```

`userAccountHasWorkgroup`has an `@Embeddable` class as ID.

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

I add more information:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserAccount_has_Workgroup")
public class UserAccountHasWorkgroup implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6537213525312531347L;

    private UserAccountHasWorkgroupId id;

    private UserAccount userAccountByUserAccountId;
    private Privilege privilege;
    private UserAccount userAccountByApprovedByUserAccountId;
    private Workgroup workgroup;
    private boolean approved;
    private boolean lastActiveWorkgroup;
    private boolean isWorkgroupReferent;

    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class UserAccountHasWorkgroupId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6368469866573301127L;
    private long userAccountId;
    private long workgroupId;

    ...
}
```

If i do:

`List<UserAccountHasWorkgroup>  result = query.list(userAccountHasWorkgroup);`

it works, but when I try to count:

`Long count = query.count();`

I receive the `DataException`

Comment: I suppose your query needs a parameter.. like user account...?A= And I suppose you are not providing it.

Comment: I guess problem is hibernate translating query in this style `SELECT count(tb) FROM Table1 tb WHERE...` in `count()` tb is passed which is not supported. `count(tb.id)` should work, take a look of `projection` in hibernate.

Comment: I've added more information in my question. Could you kindly provide me an example of the query count syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

`query.count();`

I do

`query.uniqueResult(Wildcard.count.as("count"));`

It seems to work properly.